# Signal no longer working on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, wifi

I had [Signal from Signal Technology Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Technology_Foundation) on my iPhone 4S. It worked until last week. Now I have to re-register my phone number with a one-time code and I see this message:

> **Verification failed.** (The operation couldn't be completed SignalServiceKit.NetworkManagerError error 401)

[image: error message]

I know the code is right because a deliberate wrong code gives a different message. The same happens whether on 3G or wifi.

I suspect that the phone is now too old for Signal because the message on the screen is truncated. Is that true?

### update

The iOS version is 9.3.6 (13G37), which should still be compatible with Signal (since I was able to install it and run it, and did not update it at the time of the change).

Comment: Did you ask Signal support for help?  That should be your first step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Signal](https://support.signal.org/) support:

> Confirm that Signal is supported by your iOS.
> Signal iOS has a minimum iOS requirement of 11.1

Highest version iPhone 4S supports is iOS 9.3.5

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Signal Support, per the comments, and the reply was:

> Signal supports older OS's for as long as possible unless there is a technical limitation. This is not a decision we took lightly. There are new features we want to add to Signal that will not work on older iOS's. Signal requires iOS 11.2 and later.